# Chef on Ubuntu 19.10: broken recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I tried to run a chef recipe on Ubuntu 19.10 that works as expected on Ubuntu 18.04.3. On both Ubuntu versions I installed chef 15.4.45-1 using the package provided on [this website](https://downloads.chef.io/chef).

```
execute 'Git LFS: Install user configuration' do
  command 'git lfs install'

  user 'myusername'

  not_if 'git config --global filter.lfs.required | grep "true"', :user => 'myusername'
end
```

I am using this command to start the chef client: `sudo chef-client -z -o "recipe[my-cookbook::my-recipe]"`

Output:

```
  * execute[Git LFS: Install user configuration] action run

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[Git LFS: Install user configuration]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
    ---- Begin output of git lfs install ----
    STDOUT: WARNING: Error running /usr/lib/git-core/git 'config' '--global' '--replace-all' 'filter.lfs.required' 'true': 'warning: unable to access '/root/.gitconfig': Permission denied
    warning: unable to access '/root/.config/git/config': Permission denied
    error: could not lock config file /root/.gitconfig: Permission denied' 'exit status 255'
    Run `git lfs install --force` to reset git config.
    STDERR: 
    ---- End output of git lfs install ----
    Ran git lfs install returned 2
```

Obviously chef executed the `not_if` guard as the root user and not the provided user `myusername`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef did execute the `not_if` clause as your `myusername`. However, when doing so, the `$HOME` environment variable wasn't updated to point to this user's HOME but remained as `/root`.

Thus, git tried to access the files in root's HOME which failed because `myusername` has no permission to access files there.

To fix this, you can pass an explicit HOME environment variable:

```
execute 'Git LFS: Install user configuration' do
  command 'git lfs install'

  user 'myusername'

  not_if 'git config --global filter.lfs.required | grep "true"', :user => 'myusername', :environment => { 'HOME' => '/home/myusername' }
end
```

See https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#arguments for details about valid arguments.

Comment: With your proposed change the command executes as expected but I don't like the idea of changing a few hundred recipes to set the environment variable manually. I am using this recipe since Ubuntu 14.04 and it always worked without explicitly setting the environment variable.